# php ajax one page contact form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

i am working on one page ajax contactform . I want to send an email with PHP without leaving my page and now i'm completely lost. I have no idea why its not working

i'll show you my contact form. thank you for help in advance. Here is the form ..

**html code**

```
<article class="panel" style="background:url(img/cover/bg_panel_3.jpg); background-size:cover;" full-screen>

    <div style="padding-top:80px;">
        <div class="row text-center centered">


            <div id="contact-form">

                <form id="contact-us" action="contact.php" method="post">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="field" id="check-1">
                            <input class="input txt requiredField wide alpha-only" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>"  placeholder="Name" onBlur="check(this.value)" />


                        </li>
                        <li class="field" id="check-2">
                            <input class="input wide mail-only txt requiredField email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" placeholder="Email" />


                        </li>
                        <li class="field" id="check-3">
                            <input class="input wide hack-check sub-check requiredField" name="subj" type="text" placeholder="Subject" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['subj']))  echo $_POST['subj'];?>" />


                        </li>
                        <li class="field" id="check-4">
                            <input class="input wide num-only requiredField" name="num" type="text" placeholder="Number" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['num']))  echo $_POST['num'];?>" />

                        </li>
                        <li class="field" id="check-5">
                            <textarea class="input textarea wide hack-check msg-check txtarea requiredField"  name="comments" id="commentsText" class="txtarea requiredField" placeholder="Message:">
                            <?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?>
                            </textarea>

                            </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="medium primary btn pretty-btn">
                        <input name="submit" class="subbutton" type="submit" value="Send" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                </form>
                <?php } ?>
                <!-- End #contact --> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**js code **

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#contact-us').submit(function() {
        $('form#contact-us .error').remove();
        var hasError = false;

                    });
        if(!hasError) {
            var formInput = $(this).serialize();
            alert(formInput);
            $.post("contact-us.php",formInput, function(data){
                $('form#contact-us').slideUp("fast", function() {                  
                    $(this).before('<p class="tick fg-white sans"><strong>Thanks!</strong> Your email has been delivered. !</p>' );
                });

            });
        }

        return false;   
    });
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {


    $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $num = trim($_POST['num']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subj']);
    $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);




$formcontent=" From : $name \n Email : $email \n Subject : $subj \n Phone number : $number \n \n Message : $message";
$recipient = "example@mail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form Query Received";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error encountered! Please try again or write directly to the mentioned email address.");

        // set our boolean completion value to TRUE
        $emailSent = true;

}
```

Comment: "not working" is not very helpful to localize the problem. Do you get any errors? My first suggest: have you installed and configured `sendmail` properly?

Comment: I think you need to check out some basics. You did not provide an acceptable example (short, only the problem for instance, behaviour, error, etc), but let me start with this: if you want to do something with post you either  leave the page (e.g. when you do submit) or you use ajax (send the post in the background (async) to the server. You seem to not want the first, but I don't see any ajax either. Read up on serverside vs clientside and how to ask a good question (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Comment: We will need more info to help you fix this. But just as a thought, are you sending non-cache headers in your PHP script? That is usually a good idea, but probably not your problem.
@Nanne there is ajax being employed, or at least there seems to be. I can't blame you for not spotting that though when the problem wasn't described clearly.

Comment: @jacob so how do you want me to describe a problem. problem is that its not showing any error but still i'm not getting any mail.

Comment: try and isolate the problem. dumping all of your code and saying it's not working is not helpful at all. Turn on error reporting, do some debugging by printing out values you expect at various stages and making sure they equal what you expect. Report back with a more specific outline of your problem, then you might get some real help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is this extra }); in your code which is stopping the $.post(...) call from even being called. A quick lint of your JS shows this up, as does careful reading.

```
var hasError = false;

======>  });  <====== remove this extra stuff.

if(!hasError) {
```